# Aruba to Juniper EX4200

Tags: switch, vlan, juniper, junos

So I have a bit of an unusual situation -- I'm trying to use a EX4200-48-PoE juniper switch with our Aruba (HP) network in place -- just as a transitional move as we're doing some construction to give users connection in a temporary space...

I have a simple vlan setup, data is native untagged and voice is tagged. Phones pickup dhcp from CX on the voice network, and clients computers on static addresses can get data through the mitel IP phones

> ```
> vlan 1
>    name "Data"
>    untagged 1-52
>    --ip address--
>    exit
> vlan 2
>    name "Voice"
>    --ip address--
>    qos priority 6
>    tagged 1-52
>    voice
>    exit
> ```

Now on the juniper switch I read documentation to match our setup and got the following, which I thought would work:

Physical interface 1 is the uplink to the Aruba, and physical interface 2 is the PoE IP phone

```
> ge-0/0/1 {
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             port-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members voice;
>             }
>         }
>     } } ge-0/0/2 {
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             port-mode access;
>             vlan {
>                 members voice;
>             }
>         }
>     } }
>
```

At the bottom of the config I have the following as well:

```
> protocols {
>     rstp;
>     lldp {
>         interface all;
>     }
>     lldp-med {
>         interface all;
>     } } ethernet-switching-options {
>     voip {
>         interface ge-0/0/2.0 {
>             vlan 2;
>             forwarding-class voice;
>         }
>         interface ge-0/0/1.0 {
>             vlan 2;
>             forwarding-class voice;
>         }
>     }
>     storm-control {
>         interface all;
>     } } vlans {
>     data {
>         vlan-id 1;
>     }
>     voice {
>         vlan-id 2;
>     } } poe {
>     interface all; }
```

So I'm able to get DHCP to the phone from the voice network, and the phone is working as normal... but the data network devices, with static addresses, connected to the network port on the phone cannot get to the data network. It's not allowing those packets even through data is untagged.

And I know these phones have this capability because it work's as intended on the Arubas.

I'm new to juniper, but I feel like this is the basic setup of all setups -- could someone give me a hand in what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How would VLAN 1 (data) get to your phones (and then to the PCs) that are connected to access ports in VLAN 2 on Juniper? It is likely that your current Aruba setup has trunk ports facing phones with native VLAN 1 (PVID) and tagged VLAN 2. Please clarify your existing setup..

Comment: I have both of the networks coming in from my firewall. 

Native data VLAN 1 is 10.xx.xx.xx/24 coming in untagged into interface 1 on the Aruba

Comment: Voice VLAN 2 is 10.50.xx.xx/24 coming in tagged into interface 2 on the Aruba

Ports where clients need voice/data I just tag the interface with voice and leave the native data vlan untagged and tag voice vlan to that port. 

Clients are able to get dhcp from voice network on the VOIP phone, and get data through the network port on the phone w/ this setup. And this works from Aruba to Aruba. 

Just not sure how to replicate this on Juniper